# Python instance method in C

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

Consider the following Python (3.x) code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        pass
foo = Foo()
```

How to write the same functionality in C?

I mean, how do I create an object with a method in C? And then create an instance from it?

**Edit**:
Oh, sorry! I meant the same functionality via Python C API. How to create a Python method via its C API?
Something like:

```
PyObject *Foo = ?????;
PyMethod??? *bar = ????;
```

Comment: Structures can contain pointers to functions. A struct is almost like a class.

Comment: I think most people are misinterpreting the question (or maybe I am), you might want to clear it up. I understand, the question is how to use the C Python API to create a python class, and instance of it. I've never used the C API, but I'm pretty sure you can only create functions, and then write the class in Python to access those functions.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: You may or may not have just made the record for 'question with the most deleted answers'. ;)

Comment: @Jeffrey: you can create classes with the C API.  Remember: all of Python's built-ins are implemented in the C API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple class (adapted from http://nedbatchelder.com/text/whirlext.html for 3.x):

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "structmember.h"

// The CountDict type.

typedef struct {
   PyObject_HEAD
   PyObject * dict;
   int count;
} CountDict;

static int
CountDict_init(CountDict *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
   self->dict = PyDict_New();
   self->count = 0;
   return 0;
}

static void
CountDict_dealloc(CountDict *self)
{
   Py_XDECREF(self->dict);
   self->ob_type->tp_free((PyObject*)self);
}

static PyObject *
CountDict_set(CountDict *self, PyObject *args)
{
   const char *key;
   PyObject *value;

   if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "sO:set", &key, &value)) {
      return NULL;
   }

   if (PyDict_SetItemString(self->dict, key, value) < 0) {
      return NULL;
   }

   self->count++;

   return Py_BuildValue("i", self->count);
}

static PyMemberDef
CountDict_members[] = {
   { "dict",   T_OBJECT, offsetof(CountDict, dict), 0,
               "The dictionary of values collected so far." },

   { "count",  T_INT,    offsetof(CountDict, count), 0,
               "The number of times set() has been called." },

   { NULL }
};

static PyMethodDef
CountDict_methods[] = {
   { "set",    (PyCFunction) CountDict_set, METH_VARARGS,
               "Set a key and increment the count." },
   // typically there would be more here...

   { NULL }
};

static PyTypeObject
CountDictType = {
   PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
   0,                         /* ob_size */
   "CountDict",               /* tp_name */
   sizeof(CountDict),         /* tp_basicsize */
   0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
   (destructor)CountDict_dealloc, /* tp_dealloc */
   0,                         /* tp_print */
   0,                         /* tp_getattr */
   0,                         /* tp_setattr */
   0,                         /* tp_compare */
   0,                         /* tp_repr */
   0,                         /* tp_as_number */
   0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
   0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
   0,                         /* tp_hash */
   0,                         /* tp_call */
   0,                         /* tp_str */
   0,                         /* tp_getattro */
   0,                         /* tp_setattro */
   0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
   Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, /* tp_flags*/
   "CountDict object",        /* tp_doc */
   0,                         /* tp_traverse */
   0,                         /* tp_clear */
   0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
   0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
   0,                         /* tp_iter */
   0,                         /* tp_iternext */
   CountDict_methods,         /* tp_methods */
   CountDict_members,         /* tp_members */
   0,                         /* tp_getset */
   0,                         /* tp_base */
   0,                         /* tp_dict */
   0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
   0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
   0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
   (initproc)CountDict_init,  /* tp_init */
   0,                         /* tp_alloc */
   0,                         /* tp_new */
};

// Module definition

static PyModuleDef
moduledef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "countdict",
    MODULE_DOC,
    -1,
    NULL,       /* methods */
    NULL,
    NULL,       /* traverse */
    NULL,       /* clear */
    NULL
};


PyObject *
PyInit_countdict(void)
{
    PyObject * mod = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
    if (mod == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    CountDictType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
    if (PyType_Ready(&CountDictType) < 0) {
        Py_DECREF(mod);
        return NULL;
    }

    Py_INCREF(&CountDictType);
    PyModule_AddObject(mod, "CountDict", (PyObject *)&CountDictType);

    return mod;
}
```

Comment: Do I really need to create a new type in order to create a simple instance method? I thought it is much more simpler....

Comment: I don't know of a way to make an instance method without an instance, and you need a class to make an instance.

Comment: Creating types seems fairly complicated. I thought creating an instance of predefined class "object" would be much simpler. But maybe it is the case that in Py3k types are the same thing as a class?

Comment: In Python 2.x also, classes are types (there are some types that aren't classes, but I'm a little murky on the details).  The C API is powerful, but not always convenient.  I felt a little silly saying, "here's a *simple* class", then pasting 143 lines of code, but that is the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 3):

You can't! C does not have "classes", it only has `struct`s. And a `struct` cannot have code (methods or functions).

You can, however, fake it with function pointers:

```
/* struct object has 1 member, namely a pointer to a function */
struct object {
    int (*class)(void);
};

/* create a variable of type `struct object` and call it `new` */
struct object new;
/* make its `class` member point to the `rand()` function */
new.class = rand;

/* now call the "object method" */
new.class();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start from the example source code [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/py3k/Modules/xxmodule.c?revision=69214&view=markup) -- it's part of Python 3's sources, and it exists specifically to show you, by example, how to perform what you require (and a few other things besides) -- use the C API to create a module, make a new type in that module, endow that type with methods and attributes.  That's basically the first part of the source, culminating in the definition of `Xxo_Type` -- then you get examples of how to define various kinds of functions, some other types you may not care about, and finally the module object proper and its initialization (you can skip most of that of course, though not the module object and the parts of its initialization that lead up to the definition of the type of interest;-).

Most of the questions you might have while studying and adapting that source to your specific needs have good answers in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/index.html), especially in the [section](http://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/objimpl.html) on "Object Implementation Support" -- but of course you can always open a new question here (one per issue would be best -- a "question" with many actual *questions* is always a bother!-) showing exactly what you're doing, what you were expecting as a result, and what you are seeing instead -- and you'll get answers which tend to include some pretty useful ones;-).

Comment: That link is about creating new types, I thought it is possible to create just a simple PyObject and somehow add a callable object (method) to it. But maybe I don't fully understand - in Python 3, are types and objects the same thing?

Comment: @Ecirh, no: all types are objects, but not all objects are types. You can add callable attributes to some objects that aren't types (such as modules), but those callable attributes won't be "method" -- they'll typically be plain functions.  If what you want is to create a new module object and add some function to it, please say so rather than so specifically mentioning "instance methods"!!!

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. You are right, I don't want precisely "instance methods", I was not aware that it is possible to satisfly `writer = PyObject_GetAttrString(f, "write");` by something other that "instance method".