# How to catch Python 3 stdout in C++ code

Tags: python-3.x, python-c-api

In an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307187/how-to-catch-python-stdout-in-c-code/) about how to catch python stdout in C++ code, [there is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307187/how-to-catch-python-stdout-in-c-code/4307737#4307737) and it works - but only in Python 2.

I would like to use something like that with Python 3. Anyone could help me here?

**UPDATE**

The code I am using is below. It was ported from Mark answer cited above, the only change was the use of `PyBytes_AsString` instead of `PyString_AsString`, as [cited in documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html).

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
std::string stdOutErr =
"import sys\n\
class CatchOutErr:\n\
    def __init__(self):\n\
        self.value = ''\n\
    def write(self, txt):\n\
        self.value += txt\n\
catchOutErr = CatchOutErr()\n\
sys.stdout = catchOutErr\n\
sys.stderr = catchOutErr\n\
"; //this is python code to redirect stdouts/stderr

Py_Initialize();
PyObject *pModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__"); //create main module
PyRun_SimpleString(stdOutErr.c_str()); //invoke code to redirect
PyRun_SimpleString("print(1+1)"); //this is ok stdout
PyRun_SimpleString("1+a"); //this creates an error
PyObject *catcher = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,"catchOutErr"); //get our catchOutErr created above
PyErr_Print(); //make python print any errors

PyObject *output = PyObject_GetAttrString(catcher,"value"); //get the stdout and stderr from our catchOutErr object

printf("Here's the output:\n %s", PyBytes_AsString(output)); //it's not in our C++ portion

Py_Finalize();


return 0;
}
```

I build it using Python 3 library:

`g++ -I/usr/include/python3.6m -Wall -Werror -fpic code.cpp -lpython3.6m`

and the output is:

`Here's the output:
 (null)`

If someone needs more information about the question, please let me know and I will try provide here.

Comment: In what way doesn't this work? The a pure Python version works fine with Python 3, so I don't see why the C-API version won't?

Comment: I will edit the question and put the code I am using.

Comment: The indentation looks wrong in `stdOutErr`. That'd be my first guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `.value` isn't a `bytes` object, it is a `string` (i.e. Python2 `unicode`) object. Therefore `PyBytes_AsString` fails. We can convert it to a `bytes` object with `PyUnicode_AsEncodedString`.

```
PyObject *output = PyObject_GetAttrString(catcher,"value"); //get the stdout and stderr from our catchOutErr
PyObject* encoded = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(output,"utf-8","strict");
printf("Here's the output:\n %s", PyBytes_AsString(encoded));
```

Note that you should be checking these result `PyObject*` against NULL to see if an error has occurred.

Comment: Thanks DavidW, your tip solve the problem with the code above. I have other doubt related to this, in the code I am working looks like the`PyUnicode_AsEncodedString` is always returning `NULL`. The other functions are working (or at least they are not returning `NULL`). Do you have any idea about what it can be?

Comment: It means it's raised an exception. You should inspect the inspection to find out what's gone wrong. That's a little harder since you redirected stderr. It's possible an arguement other than "strict" might make it work.